# how to get max repeated count with sql

Tags: mysql, count

Hi have a table name is cou

```
name      type

kasu      1
kasu      4
kasu      3
nimal     1
nimal     2
```

I need this answer as

```
name  cnt

kasu  3
```

Comment: In what way is `"kasu" 3" the max? What about `"kasu" 4`? What hvae you tried yourself?

Comment: what if I have additional row as nimal 3?? What would be output??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS `cnt`
FROM cou 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY `cnt` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

ok so, sorry, i didn't find something more elegant, so I did it the stupid way. There is definetly another way of doing it though...

### [Demo with your example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e906b/20)

### [Another Example after adding inputs](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea5bb/1)

Comment: Always add demo.. I have edited your answer and added Demo as link

Comment: I'm trying to help, so if nobody thinks it helps I'll remove the answer as I always do, it's just fine :-)

Comment: your answer is correct.. I have provided link. If you want to add then KEEP it or REMOVE it.. Gotcha??

Comment: Yeah, everything is fine.. just don't give advice using imperative mode, gotcha??

Comment: The user has to answer this question :-) you pointed it out correctly but I think here our job is finished...